# Authentication with Cordova and Java backend

Tags: ios, spring, cordova, spring-boot, spring-security

I have spring boot based backend which is using spring security. It exposes Restful API to mobile cordova app. 
The authentication is based on cookie, however the users get logged out even there is persisted token and cookie max age is set to huge number. I can't locate the exact reason but i think that some devices are removing the cookie on certain cases.

What's the proper way to implement authentication with cordova and spring security so that the users don't get logged out, but constantly be logged in once authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

as you know cookies won't work for you. You can use the [LocalStorage/WebSQL](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html)

Both the approach will help you to save your data in mobile. In your case WebSQL will be better option, but now you have to configure your application code to use stored value before sending each request. **Ex: set authentication information in http header before each sending request**

You can use [cordova-plugin-secure-storage](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage) or else if you can use social login then you can go for **Auth0**

Comment: I already considered using localStorage, however from what i read it's not save as other apps can read the data from my app.
Re WebSQL - it seems it's not supported by all devices and i don't need to store any complex data structures but simple string token.

Comment: Yes, but there are other SQLite Plugin too, which you can use. Yes sure you just have to store simple token only, but I believe this will be the best approach for cordova application. i have edited the answer too